# What is the best approach for control version branching in Scrum?

Tags: svn, version-control, branch, branching-strategy

Having multiple teams working on a single product with a single Product Backlog, is it a good idea for each member of those teams to frequently commit their code to the trunk, rather than having branches for each team?

So they would be working separately on Sprints, synchronize the trunk and their branches frequently after code reviews and add their working code within to their branch(es) first?

Or

What could be the approach we can use, is there any standard model for it?

Comment: **Any** sprint around SVN is **Bad Idea (tm)**

Answer (score 3):

Continuous Integration (to trunk) is a great state to aim for. A simple policy for branching is: Don't

I agree that sometimes you have no chance but to branch. In those circumstances, realize that when you do this, you are incurring a compound technical debt. The longer you leave the debt unpaid, the more it accumulates.

If you *have* to branch, do it as late as possible and merge back as early as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Committing frequently to the trunk can be confusing especially if there are frequent commits.  One approach is to use a feature branch approach where a feature is worked on in a separate branch until it's complete, then it's merged into the trunk/master.  That way you only are committing to master when you strongly believe a feature to work.  If trunk/master has changed in the meantime, you can simply pull that down into the feature branch and fix any conflicts there.

As Derek said, continuous integration to trunk/master is a goal to strive for.  It may just be that you don't want so much confusion around commits with comments like "oops, forgot that config", "trying one more time", "almost there...", etc.

Comment: I wouldn't wait until it's complete, merge it each time it's stable (enough). If you wait too long to merge, it's going to be hell. And you're going to have huge test "phases" after each merge.